# unix inline script including another script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have two different script
1st one is

```
sar -u -s 11:00:00 -e 11:10:59 | grep Average: | awk '{printf($8)}'
```

2nd one will show the time which is 60 min old

```
date -d '60 minute ago' "+%H:%M:%S"
```

I want to use 2nd sctipt in 1st script (without creating any .sh file)
Below code is not working

```
sar -u -s `date -d '60 minute ago' "%H:%M:%S"` -e 11:10:59 | grep Average: | awk '{printf($8)}'
```

Comment: What exactly does _is not working_ mean?

Comment: If you would have tried running the command you wrote, the shell would tell you what's wrong. `argument must be a format string beginning with '+'`. Give it a try.

Comment: I want to use the result of a 2nd command as input for a 1st command @user1934428

Comment: Your "1st command" is a _sar_ command. While I have never used _sar_, it does not, AFIK, process _standard input_. Please specify in your question (not in a comment), what you understand under **input for** the 1st command. Perhaps you mean "you want to use the standard output of the 2nd command as a parametre for the 1st command"? But this is what you already did in the code you posted; you only forgot to copy over the `+` sign. BTW, using `$(....)` instead of backquotes is more idiomatic for doing command substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try this, your second command seems not to work, it should be:

```
date -d '60 minute ago' "+%H:%M:%S"
```

(Mind the "+" at the beginning of your format string)

When I use this, using `$(...)` instead of the accent graves, for readability, everything seems to be working fine:

```
echo $(date -d '60 minute ago' "+%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: @ceving: not useless: I demonstrated, using echo, how to use the result of a first command as  input for a second command.

Comment: you are right. it was the about that + sign
`sar -u -s `date -d '60 minute ago' "+%H:%M:%S"` -e 11:10:59 | grep Average: | awk '{printf($8)}'`